# Классы, наследование. почтовое отделение

Tags: python, классы, dataclass

В  отделении почты есть посылки. На каждой посылке есть код и пин. Посылка регистрируется под текущей датой и под статусом «Зарегистрирована» . Когда посылка доходит до пункта приема, она принимается (меняется статус посылки и дата получения записываются). Наконец, когда прибывает получатель, он сообщает номер посылки (код и пин). Если он дает эти данные правильно, то получает посылку (отмечаем дату выдачи и меняем статус на «получено»). Кроме того, нужно записать имя и фамилию получателя. Некоторые посылки являются неоплаченными. Для них сумма должна быть указана при регистрации. доплаты. Следует разработать классы Paczka(посылка), Получатель(odbiorca) и Пункт получения(punkt odbioru). Класса пункт получение  должен позволять распечатать список посылок с их статусом и историей (дата регистрация, прием и сбор).
В чем ошибка этого кода?

```py
import datetime 


class Paczka:
    def __init__ (self,pin,kod,status):
        self.pin = pin
        self.kod = kod
        self.status="rejestrowana"
    
    def data_rejestracji(self):
        data_rejestracji=datetime.date.today()
        print('paczka', pin, kod, data_rejestracji) 


class Odbiorca:
    def __init__(self,godność,pin1,kod1,status1):
        self.godność= imienazwisko
        self.pin1 = pin
        self.kod1 = kod
        self.status = "Odebrana"
        if pin in self.pin1(Odbiorca) == self.pin(Paczka):
            print('pin jest poprawny')
        elif kod in self.kod1(Odbiorca) == self.kod(Paczka):
            print ("Odebrana")

    def data_odbioru(self):
        data_rejestracji=datetime.date.today()
        print('paczka', pin, kod, data_odbioru) 


class Punkt_odbioru(Paczka,Odbiorca): 
    def __str__ (self):
        return f'Punkt_odbioru {self.status}\t{self.data_rejestracji}\t{self.data_przyjęcia}\t{self.data_odbioru}'
        
     
   return Punkt_odbioru(self.data_rejestracji+data_przyjęcia)][1]][1]
```

Comment: У вас там переменные на польском что-ли? :D

Comment: добавьте в вопрос трейс ошибок?